# Unable to import uploaded Python wheel in Databricks

Tags: python, databricks, python-wheel

[Also posted on the official forum](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/31129/unable-to-import-uploaded-wheel-no-module-named.html), reposting here for visibility.

Completed all the steps from [here](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries.html) to upload a custom Python wheel to Databricks. I've built a simple test wheel called `somelongexamplename` and compiled it to a `.whl` using Pyhton 3.5.2 . It's very simple and only has one module with one method that prints `"Hello world"`.

I've created a library in the Shared folder in the workspace in Databricks and then created a custom Cluster (v5.5) and installed the wheel on that one. Screenshots below show the library installed on the cluster and the cluster with the library installed.

[image: library with successful installation]

[image: cluster with library installed]

It is similarly visible on the databricks-cli as shown below.

[image: databricks-cli showing installation]

Running the below command in a notebook attached to the testing cluster also shows the wheel installed correctly.

```
%sh
/databricks/python/bin/pip freeze
```

Yet still when I run:

```
import somelongexamplename
```

I get:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-194690> in <module>()
----> 1 import somelongexamplename

ImportError: No module named 'somelongexamplename'
```

Does anyone have an idea of what may be causing this? I can't seem to find any other online resources that provide a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in my `setup.py` file all along. I had a misconfigured `packages` value in the `setup` method.

It was initially this:

```
setup(
    ...
    packages=find_packages(where='somelongexamplename'),
    package_dir={'': 'somelongexamplename'},
    ...
)
```

Changing it to this fixed it for me:

```
setup(
    ...
    packages=['somelongexamplename'],
    ...
)
```

If you're encountering this issue, please ensure you have your wheel configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine. I installed a wheel pacakage and tried importing. It got successfully imported. Just try detach and reattach the notebook.

[image: SuccessFully Installation of Wheel Package]
[image: Successfully Imported the wheel package]

Comment: Have tried detaching + reattaching multiple times to no avail. Could you provide more information on how you built the wheel and how you then installed it please?